# How to prevent cloud function from triggering for a parent node after changing a field in its child node?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase Realtime Database is structured like below:

```
-- Stock
   -- StoreId
      -- DepartmentId_1
         -- ProductId_1
            -- name: "productName"
            -- price: 1.0
      -- DepartmentId_2
         -- ProductId_X
            -- name: "productNameX"
            -- price: 1.0
```

I would like to read the `DepartmentId`s to show them in a `RecyclerView`. But the Android Firebase Listener retrieves all the data contained in the `StoreId`.

I know I can use a for loop and get the keys, but that is not the point. The problem is the amount of data downloaded and that could explode my quota in Firebase.

So, I decided to use Cloud Functions for writing of the keys in other node like below:

```
-- Departments
   -- StoreId
      -- DepartmentId_1: true
      -- DepartmentId_2: true
      -- DepartmentId_3: true
      -- DepartmentId_4: true
              .
              .
              .
```

I thought Cloud Functions would only trigger in a specific node, but it turned out that if I change the `price` field, my `Cloud Function` is triggered.

So my question is: How to trigger my Cloud Function only when either a `departmentId` is added or removed?

Below is my first step, so how to loop through the `departmentId`s and write them in the **Departments** node?

```
exports.createStoreDepartments = functions.database
.ref('Stock/{storeId}')
.onWrite((change,context) => {
  console.log('DATA CHANGED');
  return true;
});
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to trigger my Cloud Function only when either a `departmentId` is added or removed?

There are two ways to do this:

1. With two separate triggers.

   ```
   exports.createStoreDepartments = functions.database
   .ref('Stock/{storeId}/{departmentId}')
   .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
       ...
   ```

   and

   ```
   exports.createStoreDepartments = functions.database
   .ref('Stock/{storeId}/{departmentId}')
   .onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
       ...
   ```
2. With a single `onWrite` trigger.

   ```
   exports.createStoreDepartments = functions.database
   .ref('Stock/{storeId}/{departmentId}')
   .onWrite((change,context) => {
       if (!change.before.exists()) {
         // TODO: this department was just created
       }
       if (!change.after.exists()) {
         // TODO: this department was just deleted
       }});
   ```

Comment: Interesting! `onCreate()` is triggered only when new `departmentId` is added (exactly what I was looking for). `onWrite()` triggers whenever a field is changed in whatever child node, even though it has the same triggers for creation and deletion. I've adopted the two separated triggers.

Comment: Good to hear what you ended up using Aliton!

Comment: How to write `departmentId: true`? Instead of the key, it is writing **departmentId** when I use `var data = {departmentId: true};`. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `var data = {[departmentId]: true};`. But that this is a completely separate question, so please keep comments for.... comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! My `Cloud Function` is ready and running.